# How can I change <br> tag with line break in SwiftSoup?

Tags: swift, swiftsoup, htmlparse

I'm trying to get a paragraph with SwiftSoup, the html has the 
 codes. When I parse it, it's just getting text without line break. How can I change 
 tags with line breaks?

```
do {
   let html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
       + "<body><p>Parsed HTML <br> into a doc.</p></body></html>"
   let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
   return try doc.text()
} catch Exception.Error(let type, let message) {
    print(message)
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Above code just print "Parsed HTML into a doc." without linebreaking.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked for me. Sorry for the duplicated question. I search the solution in SwiftSoup questions.

Comment: this is not a duplicate question